# CSS Layouts and inline-block with width %

Tags: html, css, layout

Im trying to create a fluid layout of 3 or more DIV boxes that can sit in a fixed or fluid container that looks like this:

[example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZife.jpg)

So far ive used display: inline-block to make two of the boxes sit next too each other, which does work, however when the width is set to 48% and margin is set to 1% (Which when everything is inline, should add up to a total of 100% if im correct?) the second div goes on to a new line.

With regards to the 3rd box, when i set the width to 98% (and then the margin of 1% that is applied) the box overhangs the container on the right...

What ive essentially ended up with is this:
[problem:](http://imgur.com/OdDxXl8)

I can alter and reduce the % to make it all 'sort of' fit how i want, but then the top two boxes and bottom large box just don't align up nicely.

For example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/23ppy.jpg

Essentially what im trying to produce is a quick snippet to use that i can add to any container on a website that provides a nice, clean layout, ready for content to be added.

(Im making a few different layouts)

Id like to try and limit how many classes are created so i can easily edit the layouts as needed.

for example:

.contentbox (the main 'settings' to make these boxes work)

.smallbox (if 3 divs are set to .smallbox one after another, the 3 will show inline)

.normalbox (if 2 divs are set to .normalbox one after another, the 2 will show inline)

.largebox (if 1 divs are set to .largebox it will go to the edge of the container)

I want to use % so irregardless of the size of the container, it will always fit without having to change width pixels etc.

Currently this is what ive got:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#container {
width: 600px;
border: thin solid #000;
}
.contentbox {
position:relative;
border-top-style: solid;
border-right-style: solid;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-left-style: solid;
border-top-color: #00F;
border-right-color: #00F;
border-bottom-color: #00F;
border-left-color: #00F;
display: inline-block;
width: 48%;
margin: 1%;
vertical-align: top;

}
.largebox {
width:100%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div class="contentbox">class="contentbox"</div>
<div class="contentbox">class="contentbox"</div>
<div class="contentbox largebox">class="contentbox largebox"</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advanced for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take into consideration that borders take up width and that the margin of 1% of either side of the large container means that it can only be less than 100% width. I set it to 94, and your small ones to 45 and set padding to 0!important; Now it works.

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0!important;
  border: thin solid #000;
}
.contentbox {
  position: relative;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-top-color: #00F;
  border-right-color: #00F;
  border-bottom-color: #00F;
  border-left-color: #00F;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 1%!important;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.largebox {
  width: 94%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Containers</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="contentbox">class="contentbox"</div>
    <div class="contentbox">class="contentbox"</div>
    <div class="contentbox largebox">class="contentbox largebox"</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That certainly is a lot better! I didnt take in to consideration the width of the borders... - one thing i have noticed though is if I expand the container to the full width of my browser and screen, the bottom box then over hangs the total width of the top too boxes (for example, clicking full screen when running your code snippet) and it does the opposite when making the browser smaller - is there a way to keep them all aligned nicely?

Comment: @PaulF i would reduce the bottom container by a percentage point, maybe 1.5 but don't mess with the small ones

Comment: I could still spot a tiny misalignment from the bottom box when the browser window was made quite small. Using what you showed me and css Calc.. ive come up with this: https://jsfiddle.net/7tmtegoc/ - seems to work perfectly now!

Comment: @PaulF no problem, you're a newbie! no hard feelings

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#container {
width: 100%;
border: thin solid #000;float:left;
}
.contentbox {
position:relative;
border:0px solid #00f;
display: inline-block;
width: 48%;float:left;box-shadow:0px 0px 2px 0px #555555;
margin: 1%;
vertical-align: top;

}
.largebox {
width:98%;margin: 1%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div class="contentbox">class="contentbox"</div>
<div class="contentbox">class="contentbox"</div>
<div class="contentbox largebox">class="contentbox largebox"</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thats a really interesting workaround, using shadows for a border rather than an actual border, looks nice and works like a charm aswell. In the end i used css calc and came up with this solution: https://jsfiddle.net/7tmtegoc/